# Arduino Pins are offset by 3?

Tags: arduino, avr, arduino-ide

int led = PH6+3;//this is equal to PH6 or D9?!?

why is it offset by 3? I should be able to use PH6 without the +3 in the arduino IDE. I am using a custom board but I have double checked that the pins are matching to where i want them to go. It would be way easier to use the PIN NAMES rather then arduino names.

Im using a ATMEGA2560 on my custom board.

arduino IDE version is 1.8.5

Comment: I'm using bare-metal avr instead of arduino but PH6 is propably a macro constant and this is equal to some constant + 3. Did you copy/paste this code or whats the problem? There is no macro for pin that you want to use?

Comment: Its more I want to be able to accurately use the pins by what the Atmel datasheet calls them. So somewhere there is a header file I need to find and fix the Macro Constants?

Comment: I think you are using this macros wrong and there is a macro for your pin. What pin do you want to use?

Comment: @user2175468 No, avr io definitons are consistent as it's just bit position in a Byte. If you want something more consistent, you can make your own core (if it doesn't exist already) with better mapping. You can take a look on MightyCore or MegaCore, there are several layouts mappings

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Hacking/PinMap2560big.png This works for finding the Digital pin number. but I was hoping to use PH6 to instead of 9.

Comment: You can, but you should use direct port manipulation instead of arduino super slow  wrappers

Comment: PH6 is just the same as 6. It's just a reminder to yourself, that you intend to use a certain bit on port H. If you really prefer that system, you don't need the Arduino  digitalWrite funktion.

Comment: If PH6 is the same as 6 then why is it referenced in that picture as Arduino pin 9?